# Django: How to override form.save()?

Tags: django, django-forms

My model has quite a few boolean fields. I've broken these up into 3 sets which I'm rendering as a `MultipleChoiceField` w/ a modified `CheckboxSelectMultiple`.

Now I need to save this data back to the DB. i.e., I need to split the data returned by a single widget into multiple boolean columns. I think this is appropriate for the `save()` method, **no?**

Question is, how do I do I do it? Something like this?

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    # code here
    return super(MyForm, self).save(commit)
```

If so... **how do I set the values?**

```
self.fields['my_field'].value = 'my_flag' in self.cleaned_data['multi_choice']
```

Or something? **Where's all the data stored?**

Comment: Or maybe this *should* go in `clean` if I'm just modifying the `cleaned_data`...

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The place you want your data to be stored is your new model instance:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
    instance.flag1 = 'flag1' in self.cleaned_data['multi_choice'] # etc
    if commit:
        instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: Don't forget to call ```self.is_valid()```. Otherwise, ```self.cleaned_data``` is not set.

Comment: @Visores, no you don't need to do that. `super().save` does it for you.

Comment: Don't forget to call `self.save_m2m()`.