# Getting the model ID from a Django form after having saved it

Tags: python, django

view.py

```
someForm = SomeForm(request.POST)
...
someForm.customSave(request.user)
```

forms.py

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Some

    def customSave(self,user):
        lv = self.save(commit=False)
        lv.created_by = user
        lv.save()
```

How can I get the id of the model (or the model) I have just saved from `someForm`?

Comment: I agree with Chris' answer below, but I was wondering why aren't you overriding the form's save rather than creating customSave.  A little more on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927305/django-how-to-override-form-save

Comment: Just the way I work really. + when I call `customSave` I know I have modified something in the `forms.py`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the behavior of [ModelForm.save](https://github.com/django/django/blob/399c6ac7cc1b95c249b964d6c6d47ded43943fde/django/forms/models.py#L351) is to return the instance, you might want to return the instance in your customSave method

```
def customSave(self, user):
    lv = self.save(commit=False)
    lv.created_by = user
    lv.save()
    return lv
```

then you can access the pk or id on the instance

```
inst = someForm.customSave(request.user)
inst.pk or inst.id
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use `lv.pk` or `lv.id`, after calling `lv.save()`. The id is set on the instance after it's saved.

Answer (score 1):

in your Model class override the save method:

```
def save(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    logger.debug(self.id)
```