# Get the id of an object after processing its form in views.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I need to get the id of the object I just kept in order to pass it in the HttpResponseRedirect:

```
def pujar_track(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    formulari = TrackForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if formulari.is_valid():                    
        formulari.save()            
        # code to get the track_id ???          
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/track/pujar/acoplar',track_id)
else:
    formulari = TrackForm()

return render(request,'principal/trackForm.html',
    {'formulari':formulari})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: how to get the id of the record just saved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253611/django-how-to-get-the-id-of-the-record-just-saved)

Comment: Actually the above question isn't specific to saving a form, but there is a better match here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144475/getting-the-model-id-from-a-django-form-after-having-saved-it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TrackForm extends ModelForm:

```
formulari = formulari.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect('/track/pujar/acoplar',formulari.id)
```

Without knowing how you're accepting the variable, I can't tell you how best to pass the argument. However, I would encourage you to use `reverse` instead of hard coding the url, which would look like:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_name', args=(),
    kwargs={'track_id': formulai.id}))
```

assuming your view accepts a keyword argument of `track_id`