# How to modify group creation form in admin page

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin

I am working on a project which would have different user groups, and user groups have different permissions on the website. Now I want to be able to create these user groups on the django admin group creation page. I need the group creation page to have some more checkboxes or many-to-many forms like different regions and features that I can assign for the groups.

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
class GroupPermission(GroupAdmin):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    if not hasattr(Group, 'locations'):
        field = models.ForeignKey(Group,blank=True,null=True)
        field.contribute_to_class(Group, 'locations')
    annotations = models.TextField()
    show_all_annotations = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    location_group = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    show_all_locations = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ("show_us_map", "Allow user to view the US Map."),
        ("show_world_map", "Allow user to view the World Map."),
        ("show_europe_map", "Allow user to view the Europe Map."),
        ("allow_download_data", "Allow user to download data."),
    )
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.group

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupPermission)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Or are there any plugins that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Membership = Group.user_set.related.through

class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Membership
    extra = 1

GroupAdmin.inlines = list(GroupAdmin.inlines) + [MembershipInline]
```

A slighter cleaner way would be to create your own `GroupAdmin`, and use `admin.site.unregister` and `admin.site.register`, rather than monkey patching as above.

Also, note that the interface is rather crude, compared to the nice many-to-many widget that Django provides, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You add model fields to your `ModelAdmin` which will have no effect. What you should do instead is:

- add the model fields to a `Model` somewhere
- create a `ModelForm` that contains all the fields you need and customize its `save` method that is described [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) and [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929671/1378264)
- use this form in the `ModelAdmin` as shown [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)

Comment: Thanks. But how can I add the model fields? I inherited the Group as MyGroup(Group), then unregister Group and register MyGroup, there's the error said /admin/auth/group/add not found

Comment: I've no experience with extending the group model, but have just found [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7669063/1378264) that's maybe useful.