# How to calculate field not included in ModelForm after other fields are submitted

Tags: django, django-forms

Let's assume we are given a following Model and ModelForm:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class A(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    c = models.IntegerField()  # either c = a * b or c = 2 * a * b

class AForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('a', 'b')
    double = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Now I want that if user checks`double` then `c`gets updated to `2 * a * b` and `a * b` otherwise.

EDIT: I want to use AForm as API, so that all my other code works with A instances through forms. Therefore I would like to encapsulate all the logic inside ModelForm.

Please help me with your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AForm(request.POST)  # Initialize form with POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            model = form.save(commit=False)  # Initialize model with form data, but do not save to db
            model.c = model.a * model.b
            if form.cleaned_data['double']:  # If double field was set true
                model.c = 2 * model.c
            model.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some-url'))
```

Note that the key piece of code here is `form.save(commit=False)`. This allows you to initialize the model with data from the form, before it is saved to the database. Then you can set or alter fields before saving the model.

Also note that you can access the value of individual form fields (such as `double`) through the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary.

Comment: This is perfectly fine, but I need to meet an additional constraint I've only added now to make the question more clear. I think this answer might be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/3929671/3128048