# I am using django 1.1. I need to override an admin model form so that I can log changes in a many-to-many field. How do I do this?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin

I am using django 1.1. I need to override an admin model form so that I can log changes in a many-to-many field. How do I do this?

Form Code:

```
    class ClientAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
        _filters = ClientFilter.objects.all()

        filter   = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=_filters,        widget=FilterWidget(urlname='client', queryset=_filters, header='Filters added'))

        class Meta:
            model = Client
```

I need to create a log entry for each filter added or removed from the form. I am new to Python/django but haver been programming for a long time, so its not the algorithm I need, its the Python code to implement it. I know I need to override the forms save method, but I am unclear what internal values to use.

Comment: If I may ask, why in the world are you using such an old version of Django?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927305/django-how-to-override-form-save

Comment: I have no idea, I have only been with this company for a fw weeks and my "native" language is PHP.

Comment: Ouch, hopefully the link I provided will help you but it is definitely past due for an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. It helped enough. Ideally I would need to short circuit the standard saving of the save_m2m() of the specific field and call a service to do it, but I am just creating the log entries directly within the save()