# Django: How to save a record in a new table before saving (user udates) the original

Tags: python, django, logging, django-models, database-backups

**Scenario:**

- Developing a question answer app.
- Here are different users can answer the questions.
- Each question may have several fields to response (2 or 3 yes/No checkboxes) and any user can update any of those any time.

**Problem:**

I need to keep a **log** (with time and user name) in a different log table every time the records got any changes.

The log table is just a look alike of the original model (e.g. ChangeLogModel) just with 2 extra fields as logDate and ChangingUser. 
This will help me to check the log and find the status of the question in any specific date.

**Possible Solutions:**

- Using signals (*...Not used to with signals, lack of detailed tutorials, documentation is not detailed too*)
- making the backup before doing any ".save()" (*... Have o idea how to do that*)
- Install any external app (*...Trying to avoid installing any app*)

**Summary:**
Basically What I am asking for is a log table where the 'state' of the original record/row/tuple would be saved to another table (i.e. logTable) prior to hit the "form.save()" trigger.
So, every time the record got updated so the LogTable will get a new row with a datestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an django package for audit and history, any of those in this [overview](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/model-audit/) for example.

I had success using [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

Comment: As you are already an user of "django-simple-history", would this package will be suitable if I want to know which fields of a model got changed by whom and when and to facilitate to create a report on the status of all my questions in a specific date.

Comment: The package creates a new table for each model with the same fields (plus 2 new fields for modification user and timestamp). The package also comes with integration for the Django admin, so you can see who changed which field and when.

Comment: Awesome! django-simple-history package will do the exactly same thing what I was looking for and plus more things. Have to explore more to come to a verdict, but till now seems excellent. I have not checked to make queries here. That's pretty important. 
Thanks again for your kind attention Dear Ralf.  Your answer really helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is just to do it straight forward. You can save the user's answer and right after that the log, wrap it with [database transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/) and rollback if something goes wrong.
Btw if the logs table has the same fields like the original model you might consider using foreign key or inheritance, depends on your program logic.

Comment: Basically What I am asking for is a log table where the 'state' of the original record/row/tuple would be saved to another table (i.e. logTable) prior to hit the "form.save()" trigger.
So, every time the record got updated so the LogTable will get a new row with a datestamp.

Comment: Yes I understand, its not that complicated to implement it by yourself.
First you need to create LogTable with FK to the question and datetime to specify when the changes has made.
Second step is to override the form.save() method and to include saving to LogTable. you can see example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927305/django-how-to-override-form-save?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is actually needs a lot of works to do to achieve what I really require. I may have to do that someday to learn the process. Meanwhile, the django-simple-history package will do the exactly same thing what I was looking for and plus more things. Have to explore more to come to a verdict, but till now seems excellent. Thanks again for your kind attention dear shomta1 :)